# Migrate from 2.1.9 to 2.2.0

Tags: magento2.2.0

General question.

What to pay attention to when migration from Magento version 2.1.9 to 2.2.0.

What are the big differences?

What are the composer commands?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Release notes for **Magento 2.2.0(OS):** [release notes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.0CE.html)

Magento update from 2.1.9 to 2.2.0: [Upgrade / Migrate From Magento 2.1.9 to Magento 2.2.0](https://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades-for-2-x/Upgrade-Migrate-From-Magento-2-1-9-to-Magento-2-2-0-GA/m-p/76123#M756)

Hope this helps.